# Download the first 5kb of a file with PHP as plain text?

Tags: php, file, download

Let's say I'd like to download some information from a file on the internet within PHP, but I do not need the entire file. Therefore, loading the full file through

```
$my_file = file_get_contents("https://www.webpage.com/".$filename);
```

would use up more memory and resources than necessary.

Is there a way to download only e.g. the first 5kb of a file as plain text with PHP?

EDIT:

In the comments it was suggested to use e.g. `maxlen` arg for `file_get_contents` or similar. But what I noticed that the execution time of the call does not vary appreciably for different `maxlen` which means that the function loads the full file and then just returns a substring to the variable.

> Is there a way to make PHP download just the required amount of bytes and no more, to speed things up?

Comment: Use the `maxlen` arg for `file_get_contents` or http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks for the suggestion! What I wonder is, if these functions open a stream of data and literally download only the required amount, or if they load the full thing but return only a substring to the variable?

Comment: @Kagaratsch you could monitor your network and see for yourself

Comment: @ADyson Indeed, monitoring the execution time (which is my primary concern) for different `maxlen` settings I found that taking 10 and 10000 lengths uses up almost the same time. Which means, it loads the full file and takes a substring...

Comment: @Kagaratsch actually I meant literally watch the HTTP request and see how much data is downloaded. Approximating that using times is not really necessary. You can see the exact amount of data transferred to your machine from the remote server and even the content. Use something like Fiddler or Wireshark.

Comment: In theory `fopen` > `fread` will only read the requested bytes and will not download anything it does not need. In practice there's a lot of buffering going on at various levels so you will always end up downloading more data than the minimum required. Most of the times this isn't a big deal because the buffer is a few kB while the total size is in the magnitude of MB but if you need to read the first 5kb of a 8kb file you're probably going to get all of the file at some level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("https://www.webpage.com/".$filename, "r");
$content = fread($fp,5*1024);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Note**: Make sure [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled.

PHP Doc: [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)